# Why are standard errors the same in lag-distributed model in R?

Tags: r, distributed

I am running a lag-distributed model ordinary least squares in which a set of units are all treated in the same year. I am including a 2 lags and 2 leads to see if there were any "anticipation" or "long-term" effects by generating the same treatment status in the previous and following years. However, when I run the model all of the standard errors are the same. For example:

```
set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), id = sort(rep(1:10,10)), years = rep(2000:2009,10))

tr <- ifelse(data$years == 2005 & data$id %in% c(2,3,4,5,6),1,0)
lead.2003 <- ifelse(data$year == 2003 & data$id %in% c(2,3,4,5,6), 1, 0)
lead.2004 <- ifelse(data$year == 2004 & data$id %in% c(2,3,4,5,6), 1, 0)
lag.2006 <- ifelse(data$year == 2006 & data$id %in% c(2,3,4,5,6), 1, 0)
lag.2007 <- ifelse(data$year == 2007 & data$id %in% c(2,3,4,5,6), 1, 0)

data <- cbind(data, tr, lead.2003, lead.2004, lag.2006 , lag.2007)

summary(lm(y ~ tr + lead.2003 + lead.2004 + lag.2006 + lag.2007, data = data))
```

Any ideas why this is? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance of your tr/lead/lag variables is the same and they are orthogonal, so they end up splitting the mean square error evenly.  The SE is calculated by sigma^2 * (X'X)^-1.  Take a look at the inverse diagonal of the covariance matrix ( (X'X)^-1 in the formula ).

```
fit <- lm(y ~ tr + lead.2003 + lead.2004 + lag.2006 + lag.2007, data = data)

X <- as.matrix(cbind(1, data[,4:ncol(data)]))
diag(solve(t(X) %*% X))
#          1         tr  lead.2003  lead.2004   lag.2006   lag.2007 
# 0.01333333 0.21333333 0.21333333 0.21333333 0.21333333 0.21333333
```

so, when you multiply this by the mean square error (sigma^2 in the formula, we can get this from an anova), and take the square root to get the standard error

```
mse <- anova(fit)[[3]][6]            # mean square error
sqrt(diag(mse * solve(t(X) %*% X)))  # SE
#         1        tr lead.2003 lead.2004  lag.2006  lag.2007 
# 0.1059099 0.4236397 0.4236397 0.4236397 0.4236397 0.4236397
```

you end up with the same standard errors for them all.

You would get different standard errors if the variables had different variances, for example, changing `lead.2003`, and rerunning the same model (the variables are still orthogonal)

```
## changed 2:6 to 3:6
lead.2003 <- ifelse(data$year == 2003 & data$id %in% 3:6, 1, 0)
## ... rerun model ...
summary(fit)$coefficients[,2]  # standard errors
# (Intercept)          tr   lead.2003   lead.2004    lag.2006    lag.2007 
#   0.1048613   0.4220586   0.4689540   0.4220586   0.4220586   0.4220586
```

Or, if the variables weren't orthogonal the standard errors would be different.

```
## again changing lead.2003
lead.2003 <- sample(c(rep(1,5), rep(0,95)), 100)
## .. rerun ..
summary(fit)$coefficients[,2]
# (Intercept)          tr   lead.2003   lead.2004    lag.2006    lag.2007 
#   0.1057283   0.4272960   0.4316341   0.4316341   0.4272960   0.4272960
```